# Is there a way to make process-internal-only conditionally-interrupting signals?

Tags: c, posix, signals, cancellation

I'm looking for a way to, from within a signal handler, conditionally interrupt a syscall that way taking place at the time the signal was handled. To make this concrete, suppose a call to `read` is in process, and `SIGRT0` is received. This signal handler uses `SA_RESTART` because it does not want to unconditionally interrupt syscalls, but depending on a condition, I want to cause `read` to return `EINTR` immediately once the signal handler returns.

One way I could do this is by setting up another signal handler for `SIGRT1`, putting `SIGRT1` in the signal mask for `SIGRT0`'s handler, and omitting `SA_RESTART` from the `SIGRT1` handler. Then the handler for `SIGRT0` can `raise` `SIGRT1`, and when the first, non-interrupting signal handler returns, the second one will fire and `read` gets interrupted.

The problem with this solution is that other processes could send `SIGRT1`, causing unwanted `EINTR` occurrences.

Is there any way to achieve the result I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I wanted was impossible for multiple reasons. Perhaps most importantly, the secondary signal that was intended to do the interrupting would potentially (and in reality on most systems) fire as soon as the first signal handler returned but *before the interrupted syscall got restarted*. Then the syscall would restart and continue to block.

Perhaps more importantly, any attempt to interrupt blocking syscalls with `EINTR` intentionally is subject to race conditions where the signal arrives just before the blocking syscall, but after whatever check would have prevented making the syscall due to having received the signal. The only time this might be acceptable is when you're prepared to fire off multiple signals with increasing delays between them until the "interupt request" is honored, but that's getting into the realm of flaky hacks...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a particular process to send that signal then you can any IPC techniques (e.g. pipe) to share its pid id and flags to make sure that signal was sent by that process. If signal wasn't sent by the process then just ignore it.

Comment: Checking the pid of the sender (which could be done with `SA_SIGINFO`, albeit with some security concerns) still would not help, because as soon as the signal handler is entered, it interrupts the syscall and causes it to return `EINTR`. I need to ensure that syscalls never return `EINTR` except for when I want them to.